# Android Studio Doesn't See Device - Linux Mint

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb, linux-mint

I tried to connect my device to android studio, on linux mint cinnamon. 
But ı have a problem about connecting. When I click run, my device doesn't seen in device list. But in the terminal, my device looks here.

> sancaryum@sancaryum-OEM ~/AndroidStudioProjects/CalismalarTemiz1 $ adb
>   devices List of devices attached  **5203d51bf497....       device**

I activated usb debugging mode and allow connection permissions on phone. Also I tried mtp,ptp connections,restarting ADB Server, reconnect the device,revoke USB Debugging on phone .. etc. I tried a lot of solution ways. 
But my device doesn't seen in android studio device list.

How can I connect my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adb_usb.ini file.

Reference: https://github.com/apkudo/adbusbini/blob/master/README.md

Comment: `adb_usb.ini` has been removed for a few years now.

Comment: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/system/core/+/115816

Comment: RGU5Android's solution way doesn't work. 
Alex P. I didn't understand this solution way :(